# How to render a 3D file using Assimp library

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, assimp

I am working on an android project, in which I need to render 3D file.
I have decided to use Assimp library after a lot of research.
I have successfully compiled Assimp library.. But I am not able to render a file using it. There is not much documentation available in this topic, I got a good [link](http://www.mbsoftworks.sk/index.php?page=tutorials&series=1&tutorial=23) which describes steps to render 3D model using Assimp, but since I am new to opengl its is very difficult for me to understand it. 
Can anyone guide me how to use it in simple steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assimp is a library for reading different types of 3D model.  It will NOT render them.

In order to do this you will need to either find a suitable rendering library or write your own, but this will not be easy if you do not have a good understanding of OpenGL.

It would greatly help you if you started at the beginning of a tutorial and worked through it.  I like [this one](https://open.gl/).  It is not Android specific, but when you understand the basics you will be able to apply the same ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Then what is Assimp-Viewer

Comment: @Abhijeet The [Assimp Viewer](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_viewer.html) is a separate project that uses the Assimp library to load the models, and then has separate code to render them.